# How to do custom tasks during install/uninstall of a ClickOnce app?

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, clickonce

Is there any way to run custom code during the installation or uninstallation of a ClickOnce app?

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1163149/7850), but that was a long time ago, the answer given there was IMHO very kludgy, and I'm kind of hoping that the later releases of VS have provided a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the following articles:

[Administering ClickOnce Deployments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/aa480721.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Installer for a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not very elegant but works:

[ClickOnce application autostart and clean uninstall or the way to customize ClickOnce installation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/506162/ClickOnce-application-autostart-and-clean-uninstal)

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce does not have the capability to do post-install or post-uninstall actions EXCEPT for the VSTO applications. Is your app a VSTO application?

Comment: @RobinDotNet mine is. How can I do that in VSTO applications?