# Creating custom registry settings during installation of Office addins

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsto, office-addins

Is there a way to inject a custom registry setting during installation of Office plugins?  Using Visual Studio 2013 and regular "publish" method that generates an .MSI file

Comment: What is the regular "publish" method?

Comment: Right click "Publish" option on the project generates a self installing .msi. however, there appear to be no configuration options that drive custom registry settings

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 Professional and have no 'publish' on right click menu, Does it VS 2013 only?

Comment: So I added the VS 2013 tag so that experts in the fields could see it and answer.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562537/how-to-do-custom-tasks-during-install-uninstall-of-a-clickonce-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for installing: Click Once and Windows Installer (.msi)

Are you sure Publish is creating an .MSI, because in a previous version of Visual Studio it makes a ClickOnce installer which is totally different from an .MSI.

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx

I don't think the ClickOnce option gives you the ability to add your own registry settings.  If you go the ClickOnce route then it would probably be easiest to add the registry setting in your addin code, assuming the registry location is something like HKCU that the user would have access to.  If you need to write to HKLM hive then that requires admin privileges and you shouldn't try doing that from your addin, it will need to be added in a .MSI that runs with admin rights.  You can use the InstallShield LE as mentioned in the article, or you could obtain the just released addin for Visual Studio that brings back the old Setup Project (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx)