# How to make a .net console app available from the command line?

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

I have a .Net Console App (written in VB) that I would like to be able to install and have available at the command prompt. When I install it, it shows up in Apps (Windows 8.1), but it isn't available if I launch a command prompt window.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop. It is a click-once app (because it defaulted to that).

I can copy the executable to the working directory and use it that way. I am using command line parameters.

What do I need to do to have it available at the command prompt after installation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the full folder path of the folder where your exe resides in the `PATH` environment variable. Windows will search there for the name of your exe.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121846/getenvironmentvariable-and-setenvironmentvariable-for-path-variable) how to do so using C#, I am sure you can convert this to VB.NET. You can even make this part of the Click Once installation, by providing a [post-deployment action or similar solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562537/how-to-do-custom-tasks-during-install-uninstall-of-a-clickonce-app).

Comment: @adrianwadey: Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

The applications you have available in command line are based on the value of the `PATH` environmental variable.

You can create your own command line shortcut with the `PATH`s you want (that's the way Visual Studio Command Prompt does this, for example), or you can change the environmental variables globally by doing `Win+Break`, `Advanced system settings` and `Environmental variables`. Add your path to `PATH` and you're done.