# Clickonce file association icon issues with Windows 10

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have create a very simple project and deployed it using Clickonce. The only problem i have is that the icon for the associated file extension i have setup is not working on windows 10.

I tried on 4 windows 10 computer and if i create a sample file "test.abcd" it shows an icon of blank sheet (the standard unrecognized icon).

I tried on 3 windows 7 and 4 windows server 2008 and all of them display my application icon on the sample file. I have ran the install as administrator on all computers. What is the extra step to do on windows 10 to make it work ? i have even tried to clean the shell icons on the windows 10 computers without success. They are all running with the UAC at the lowest setting and all account are local admin too.

I also tried remote desktop to a windows 10 computer to see if there is any difference and it doesn't work either.

**Edit** after countless tests and even recreated the project twice i figured out the problem is only on windows 10

here a sample (on left windows 7 on right windows 10) You clearly see that the file association image is not working. Both ARE associated because if i double click the file the application starts and load the file.
[image]

**Edit** adding how association work in clickonce
[image]

**Edit** I recently build 3 new computer with windows 10 and 2 Windows 7. The problem still exists. I tried putting a dozen large random progID and no matter the progId the icons are displayed on the 2 windows 7 computer but not on windows 10.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/clickonce-file-associations-break-after-windows-10/5219d142-aa6d-4f1b-af02-10ac8c603f2c?auth=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562506/windows-10-cannot-associate-file-to-clickonce-application) helps you solve or at least work around the problem

Comment: Thanks but I do not have any problem with file association. The association works perfectly on ALL windows platforms. The problem is the icon is not showing on the associated file type on Windows 10 only.

Comment: How are you registering the file association and icon?

Comment: I have no idea. click once does it if you check the option

Comment: Are you sure `1` is a good value for `ProgID`? MSDN says: "A string uniquely identifying the file type, to mark it in the registry."  If that has to be unique on the entire computer, there could be a conflict. I would try using a GUID to see if that has any effect.  There may be something else specific to Windows 10 that is using `1` as a `ProgID` that is taking precedence over you.

Comment: ...Examples I'm seeing online are showing things like `MWadePad.Document`, `Writing.Document`, and `Text.Document`.

Comment: @Franck Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @Juan no. Still not working. No answer from Microsoft side either. We kept trying on new computers and last time we tried was last July when we got a batch of 22 new computers with windows 10, none of them worked. I went to try tutorial sample project i found on the web and i hoped i would just have needed to change the source code but no, even the project unchanged cannot work on windows 10

Comment: @Franck Just installed my app on a Win 7 machine and it does show the icon, so this is definitely a bug in Win 10/8. Did you try opening a bug report at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com?

Comment: @Juan i made someone open an issue before posting the issue on stack over a year ago.

Comment: @Franck Been trying to find the issue without luck. Mind sharing the link to the issue if you have it around so I can upvote/follow/comment on?

Comment: @Juan was done by an intern that is not here anymore, i have no clue. We had to go another route and get away from click once as it's an unstable piece of crap.